# The .fadeIn function isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

I am very new to jQuery, so please be patient.

I´d like to fade in a list step by step. But anything is wrong with my function. Please can somebody help me?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: I have take a look on everything and can´t find any mistakes. The body have the needed class.

```js
$(".sideThree ul").children().each(function(i) { 
  if ($('body').hasClass("content-three-has-open")){ 
    $(".sideThree ul").css('display','block');
    $(this).fadeIn((i++) * 500); 
  } 
});
```

```css
.sideThree ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.sideThree ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  float: left;
  padding: 25px;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  width: 49%;
  margin-right: 1%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="sideThree-content">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-16">
    <ul>
      <li>// some content</li>
      <li>// some content</li>
      <li>// some content</li>
      <li>// some content</li>
      <li>// some content</li>
      <li>// some content</li>
      <li>// some content</li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: please add your **HTML** code !

Answer (score 1):

You just need to call `.fadeIn` and pass your delay value as a parameter, e.g. `$(this).fadeIn((i++) * 500);`.

Here is a Codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xXrNLr

(I'm presuming it's intentional that you want the delay to increment per list item, if not you'd just do `i * 500` as the delay).

Edit: If your list is initially set to display: none, you can add this line inside your if statement:

```
$(".sideThree ul").children().each(function(i) { 
  if ($('body').hasClass("content-three-has-open")){ 
    $(".sideThree ul").css('display','block');
    $(this).fadeIn((i++) * 500); 
  } 
});
```

Alternatively change the CSS so it's the list items that are display: none, I believe fadeIn() will set them to display prior to fading.

Comment: Thanks for helping. But anywhere i have an issue. In CSS the list is set to display: none; and the function looks now: 

`$(".sideThree ul").children().each(function(i) {
    if ($(document.body).hasClass("content-three-has-open")){
        $(this).fadeIn((i++) * 500);
    }
   });`

Comment: I've added a bit more to my answer, does this help?

Comment: Thanks! I don´t know what´s happening. The function is working great without the if statement. As soon as i use the if statement nothing works as it should.

Comment: Sorry, I just copy/pasted the if statement without properly looking at it, that's not the usual way to reference the body element so I'm not sure if that's the root of your new issue - I've updated the answer again, hopefully it will work now, is the body class definitely there?

Comment: No problem. I have update my post. Please take a look. I don´t know where i have make mistakes. Everything looks fine.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, in your updated example there is a mismatch between the class name in the HTML (sideThree-content) versus your styles/JavaScript (sideThree). Here, I updated the codepen to show it working: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eGEmwY - hope that helps :)